# Creating an observable that properly dispatches errors?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm learning Rx and am working through some of the semantics.  As an experiment, I'm building an observable timer that calls OnError on the tenth tick.  So far, I have 2 methods that I believe exhibit identical behavior:

```cs
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

// method 1
Observable.Create<long>(
    x => timer.Subscribe(tick => {
        if (tick == 10)
        {
            x.OnError(new Exception());
        }

        x.OnNext(tick);
    }));

// method 2
timer.Select(x => {
        if (x == 10)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return x;
    });
```

Am I correct in assuming that both of these methods will behave exactly the same?  If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd way is *not* equivalent, throwing in a selector results in Undefined Behavior That Might Happen To Look The Same™. Here's a few more ways:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
    .Take(9)
    .Concat(Observable.Throw<long>(new Exception("Die!")));

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
    .SelectMany(x => {
        if (x < 10) return Observable.Return(x);
        return Observable.Throw<long>(new Exception("Die!"));
    });
```